# Python - looking for a way to stop a function being called temporarily in a infinte while loop

Tags: python, sikuli

i have a while loop as my main function. within it i check several IF statements and call functions accordingly. one particular function i dont want to call if it has been run already within the last two minutes. i dont want to put a WAIT() statement in the function because i want the other IF tests to be performed duiring that time.

the code is something like this before any attempt at pausing myFunction()

```
while not(exit condition):
    if(test):
        otherFunction()
    if(test):
        otherFunction()
    if(test):
        myFunction()
```

i want myFunction() to only run at most once every two minutes. i could put a wait(120) within it but that would prevent otherFunction() being called in that time.

i tried

```
import time

set = 0
while not(exit condition):
    if(test):
        otherFunction()
    if(test):
        otherFunction()
    if(test):
        now = time.clock()
        diff = 0
        if not(set):
            then = 0
            set = 1
        else:
            diff = now - then
            if (diff > 120):
            myFunction()
            then = now
```

without success. not sure if it is the right approach, and if it is, if this code is correct. my first time working in Python (actually Sikuli) and i dont seem to be able to trace execution through to see how that is being executed.

Comment: `set` is a bad variable name. It masks the `set()` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're basically on the right track, but here's how I'd implement it:

```
import time

MIN_TIME_DELTA = 120

last_call = time.clock() - (MIN_TIME_DELTA+1)  # init to longer than delta ago
while not exit_condition:
    if test:
        otherFunction()
    if test:
        anotherFunction()
    if test and ((time.clock()-last_call) > MIN_TIME_DELTA):
        last_call = time.clock()
        myFunction()
```

**Edit**

Here's a slightly optimized version:

```
next_call = time.clock() - 1  # init to a little before now
while not exit_condition:
    if test:
        otherFunction()
    if test:
        anotherFunction()
    if test and (time.clock() > next_call):
        next_call = time.clock() + MIN_TIME_DELTA
        myFunction()
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. my first time using stack overflow and i am in awe that i am able to draw upon your experience. - Antikythera

Comment: @Anti: You're welcome...to SO. BTW, in Python, unlike many other programming languages, you likely don't need to have the parentheses around `test`, i.e. just `if test` or `if test and ...` -- they don't hurt, but it's kind of a naive thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You always set "now" to the current time. In the else branch you always set "then" to now. So diff is then always the time that passed between the last two executions of the if clause. The value of "set" is only changed on in your code and never set back to "0".

You could do something like this instead (warning: untested code):

```
import time

set = 0
last_call_time = time.clock()

while not(exit condition):
    if(test):
        otherFunction()
    if(test):
        otherFunction()
    if(test):
        now = time.clock()
        diff = now - last_call_time
        if (diff > 120)
            myFunction()
            last_call_time = now
```